# Multi-module release reporting SNAPSHOTS

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi-module maven project that I have successfully released in the past using the maven-release-plugin.  When I try and do the release now it reports that I have still have SNAPSHOTS in my dependencies.  All the SNAPSHOTS are from other projects in the multi-module parent project and I have autoVersionSubmodules=true.

```
Project
| pom.xml     // multimodule pom
|-BasePOM
| | pom.xml   // This is parent pom to all projects
|-Proj1
| | pom.xml
|-Proj2
| | pom.xml   // contains dependency to Proj1
```

The only version information is in the BasePOM/pom.xml and the  reference in each of the project poms.  Dependencies versioning is done using ${project.version}

BasePOM/pom.xml

```
<groupId>org.something</groupId>
<artifactId>BasePOM</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<!--other stuff -->

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <tagBase>${svn_root}/tags</tagBase>
                <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
                <updateDependencies>true</updateDependencies>
                <useReleaseProfile>false</useReleaseProfile>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Project/pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>BasePOM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>BasePOM/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<!--other stuff -->

<modules>
    <module>BasePOM</module>
    <module>Proj1</module>
    <module>Proj2</module>
</modules>
```

Proj1/pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>BasePOM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../BasePOM/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<!--other stuff -->
```

Proj2/pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.something</groupId>
    <artifactId>BasePOM</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>../BasePOM/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>

<!--other stuff -->

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>Proj1</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any thoughts about why maven is reporting that I have "remaining snapshot dependencies"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem.

The above use of multi-module is good.  My actual code had a dependency to an project that used to be in the code but was removed.  That meant that the artifact was in the maven repository so my code built fine.  It wasn't until I tried to do a release that the maven-release-plugin marked the errant SNAPSHOT as being unresolved.  Because the deleted project had a similar name to other projects, I didn't realize it was a mistake when I was trying to diagnose this problem.

I spent a full day trying to figure out why the maven-release-plugin was not working like it used to.  Note to self: pay special attention to what the error message actually says, not what you think the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

`BasePOM` is not a module of your reactor, so it is not affected by `autoVersionSubmodules = true`.

Comment: That was a typo when I created the question.  Sorry about that.  I will correct it.